# Filtering empty arrays from array of arrays in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have an array of arrays of type `String`, which looks something like:

```
[[""],["lorem ipsum", "foo", "bar"], [""], ["foo"]]
```

What I'd like to do is filter out all of the elements in the array that are themselves an empty array (where in this instance, by "empty array", I mean arrays that contain just an empty string), to leave me just with:

```
[["lorem ipsum", "foo", "bar"], ["foo"]]
```

However I'm struggling to find a way to do this (still new to Scala) - any help much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: But they are not empty; they contain a String

Comment: Apologies, that's my poor phrasing of it. I'll amend my question to clarify.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit (with Rogach's simplification):

```
array.filterNot(_.forall(_.isEmpty))
```

Comment: I believe that x.isEmpty is not needed here - if `x` is indeed empty, `x.forall(_.isEmpty)` would still return true.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Rogach.  You're absolutely right.  I incorporated your suggestion in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your description you ask how to

> filter out all of the elements in the array that ... contain just an
>   empty string.

The currently accepted answer does this, but also filters out empty arrays, and arrays containing multiple empty strings (i.e. not just `[""]`, but `[]` and `["", "", ""]` etc. as well. (In fact, the first part `x.isEmpty ||` is completely redundant.) Translating your requirement literally, if your array is `xss`, you need

```
xss.filter(_ != Array(""))  // does not work!
```

This doesn't work because the `equals` method for Java arrays [doesn't work as you might expect](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3487). Instead, when comparing Arrays, use either `sameElements` or `deep`:

```
xss.filterNot(_ sameElements Seq(""))

xss.filter(_.deep != Seq(""))
```

In idomatic Scala code you don't use `Array` much, so this doesn't crop up too often. Prefer `Vector` or `List`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could use:

```
array.filterNot(_.corresponds(Array("")){_ == _})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following:

```
val a = Array(Array(), Array(), Array(3,1,2016), Array(1,2,3026))

a.filter(_.length>0)
```

Comment: Please format your code accroding to this site’s guidelines (either including it in backquotes or indenting it of an appropriate number of spaces) so that it appears in a monospaced font on a grey background. Also, try to apply your solution to the given input and show that it produces the desired output. Welcome to this site!

Comment: thanks a lot，it‘s my first time to commit the answer，i will be better next time;

Comment: @tuitui You can edit your answer via the small "edit" text below it. I will do this for the moment, however.